# combine rxjs takeUntil, catchError in redux-observable AJAX epic

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I seek to 'cancel' (`takeUntil`) the AJAX call in the following redux-observable epic, while preserving the `catchError` effect.

```
const someEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(REQUEST_MAPPED_ESTABLISHMENTS),
    map( action => ( // transform data to url )),
    mergeMap( url  =>
      ajax({ url }).pipe(
        mergeMap( establishments => {
          const { error, data } = establishments.body
          if (error) throw 'some error';
          return of(actions.receiveMappedEstablishments(data))
        }),
        catchError(error =>
          (of(actions.requestMappedEstablishmentsFailure(error)))
        ),
      )
    ),
  )
```

How can the above excerpt be restructured to include `takeUntil`, for example, the following?

```
takeUntil(action$.ofType(UI_HAS_CHANGED_SO_NEW_DATA_NOW_REQUIRED))
```

So far in my attempts, I have only succeeded in canceling `someEpic` altogether, for example, inserting `takeUntil` into `action$.pipe`.

Comment: Please explain what nwse is.

Comment: `takeUntil` ... what? Another action?

Comment: Thank you for your interest: please see requested changes made.

Answer (score 0):

```
const someEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(REQUEST_MAPPED_ESTABLISHMENTS),
    map( action => ( // transform data to url )),
    mergeMap( url  =>
      ajax({ url }).pipe(
        mergeMap( establishments => {
          const { error, data } = establishments.body
          if (error) throw 'some error';
          return of(actions.receiveMappedEstablishments(data))
        }),
        catchError(error =>
          (of(actions.requestMappedEstablishmentsFailure(error))),
        takeUntil(action$.ofType(UI_HAS_CHANGED_SO_NEW_DATA_NOW_REQUIRED)) 
        ),
      )
    ),
  )
```